# Не проходят исходящие подключения от сервера

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, ping

Не могу подключиться со стороны сервера вообще к чему бы то ни было. При этом все сайты на сервере (за исключением сайтов с API, поднятым на ноде и делающим запросы) работают штатно, ssh и т.д. так же без проблем.

Изначально грешил на ошибки dns, потом выяснил, что сервер не подключается вообще ни к чему даже по ip. Даже устройства в локальной сети не пингует (кроме localhost, конечно же).

Есть интересный момент - сервра физически стоят не у меня, а у дружественной конторы.
Так что последнее предположение пошло в сторону наличия файервола на в их сети.

Как можно проверить его наличие, блокирует ли именно он, или есть другие варианты?

Comment: через `curl --verbose ` пробовали обратиться к серверу? можно посмотреть на каком этапе затыкается

Comment: маршрут по умолчанию ведёт не туда, куда вам надо?